# How to set up Movieclip names to be refrenced by array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

Ok I have a bunch of movieclips named p1, p2, p3, ..., pn all with actionscript identifiers the same as their names.

I would like to then say for an array looping through all of them, take "P" + i.y and change it.

So I would like to do this:

```
if (e.offsetY == 1) {
    "thisp" + currentPage.y ++;
}
```

even making it a variable does not work

```
var movieclipName = "thisp" + .toString(currentPage)
novieclipName.y ++;
```

??

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
var currentPage:int = 0;
var movieclipName:MovieClip = this["p"+currentPage];
movieclipName.y ++;
```

Comment: works. thank you.
Unfortunately, I am not a high enough level to uprank. haha.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [getChildByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29).

You have them all named "P" plus a number. Okay, call like this:

```
var thisp:DisplayObject=this.getChildByName('p'+currentPage);
thisp.y++;
```

Comment: but what if the movieclip p1 is not a child of whatever flash thinks is "this"?

Comment: Well, it's possible, if so, use alternate solution (right above). Also, use a "tick" button to accept an answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Even if you have 1 reputation, you can tick an answer. An upvote is an up arrow above the big number, which indeed requires 10 rep. A tick is located below the downvote arrow.

Comment: @Jim It was so long ago I've forgot. Thanks.